# MS Word Restricting Header to Subset of Document

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS Word, how can I restrict the Page Header (and Footer) to a subset of the document? I don't want them to appear on every page.

Comment: belongs definitely on superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is accomplished using Section Breaks from the *Insert* menu. Once you define a section you can then modify its header without affecting the rest of the document by first turning off **Same as Previous**. [Here](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections.htm) is a good resource for working with sections. I would suggest reading through it thoroughly before attempting this because working with sections can be tricky if you're not familiar with how Word uses them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up sections. Sections are bigger units than paragraphs, and they can have their individual headers and footers.